# Using template function for accessing the raw bytes of POD data type and strings

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to make a function template that lets me process the raw bytes of a POD data type *and* strings.

I came up with this somewhat naive approach (I'm not using template a lot, and I'm able to write them use them only for very simple cases):

```
#include <cstdio>

template<typename T>
void PrintBytes(T object)
{
  unsigned char* p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&object);
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof object; i++)
  {
    printf("%02x ", *p++);
  }

  printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
  int a = 10;
  PrintBytes(a);    // works as expected      
  short b = 12;
  PrintBytes(b);    // works as expected    
  const char* foo = "ABC";
  PrintBytes(foo);  // works as expected, but doesn't do what I want
  const char bar[] = "ABC";
  PrintBytes(bar);  // works as expected, but doesn't do what I want
}
```

Output

```
0a 00 00 00
0c 00
a4 ac 5b 8c f6 7f 00 00
a4 fb 7f 07 b7 00 00 00
```

Desired output for the last two cases

```
41 42 43
41 42 43
```

Obviously the first two cases work and the last two cases don't because `foo` and `bar` are already pointers and the `unsigned char* p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&object)` should rather be `unsigned char* p = object` and the `sizeof object` should be `strlen(object)`.

How can this be done with C++ templates? I can use c++17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use C++17 `if constexpr` to perform the corresponding address and size method according to the type of `T`, something like this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
void PrintBytes(T object)
{
  auto [p, size] = [&] {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, const char*>)
      return std::pair{object, strlen(object)};
    else
      return std::pair{reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&object), sizeof(object)};
  }();
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    printf("%02x ", *p++);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/abcTMEf8K)

Comment: This is really elegant. You should mention  that `#include <utility>` is required. OTOH I'm not sure if `#include <type_traits>` is required.

Comment: The standard does not guaranteed that `<utility>` includes `<type_traits>`, so `#include <type_traits>` is required.

Answer (score 1):

Let's expand what the compiler does when calling PrintBytes with a character array or pointer.

You call:

```
const char* foo = "ABC";
PrintBytes(foo);  // works as expected, but doesn't do what I want
```

The compiler must then instantiate the function PrintBytes for the given argument, a const char*, which gives:

```
void PrintBytes(const char* object)
{
  unsigned char* p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&object);
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof (object); i++)  // sizeof(const char*) is 8, for a 64 biut app.
  {
    printf("%02x ", *p++); // this will print the value of object, NOT what it points to.
  }

  printf("\n");
}
```

To force PrintBytes(const char*) to print the cntexnts of a string, and not its address, you should create a type specific override for strings, as in:

```
void PrintBytes(const char* sz)
{
  // you may want to check for sz itself being NULL before proceding
  if (sz)
  {
    do
    {
      printf("%02x ", *sz); // this will print the value of object, NOT its address
    } while (*sz++ != 0);
  }

  printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

void PrintBytes(const unsigned char *p, size_t len)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    printf("%02x ", *p++);
  }

  printf("\n");
}

template<typename T>
void PrintBytes(T object)
{
  const unsigned char* p = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&object);
  PrintBytes(p, sizeof object);
}

template<>
void PrintBytes(const char *object)
{
  auto len = strlen(object);
  const unsigned char* p = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(object);
  PrintBytes(p, len);
}

template<>
void PrintBytes(char* object)
{
  auto len = strlen(object);
  const char* p = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(object);
  PrintBytes(p);
}


int main()
{
  int a = 10;
  PrintBytes(a);   // works as expected
  
  short b = 12;
  PrintBytes(b);   // works as expected

  float f = 1.2f;  
  PrintBytes(f);   // works as expected

  const char* foo = "ABC";   // works as expected
  PrintBytes(foo);

  char bar[] = "ABC";  // works as expected
  PrintBytes(bar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

template<typename T>
void PrintBytes(T& object)
{
  const unsigned char* p = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&object);
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof object; i++)
  {
    printf("%02x ", p[i]);
  }

  printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
  int a = 10;
  PrintBytes(a);    // works as expected      
  short b = 12;
  PrintBytes(b);    // works as expected

  const char* foo = "ABC";
  PrintBytes(foo);
  // Print the content of the pointer foo, which is an address;
  // I think this work as expected as the "object" is just a pointer;
  // if you want to print the content of the data it points to instead,
  // you need another implementation logic of this "PrintBytes",
  // which would be an function overload, like some other answers show.

  const char bar[] = "ABC";
  PrintBytes(bar);  // print "41 42 43 00"
}
```